# Vue DOM not updating while using fetch API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch-api

I ran into an issue with Vue today, I've created a simple Vue application to demonstrate the problem. The IP I'm using for my `GET` request is timing out since I turned the server off. In the console it does log the "Fetch error" message which is exactly what I want since I wan't to create an error page on timeout.

But when I look at the HTML, it doesn't update the message, until I hit refresh at which point it will quickly change and reload. I'm pretty sure this has to do with the timeout but it seems unlikely that it's locking the Vue DOM?

I'm just very confused by the fact that it DOES `console.log` but doesn't update the HTML, even when I force-update the Vue app, does anyone know whats is wrong here? :)

I'm using Vue 3.0.0 with TypeScript and nothing else. This issue occurs on FireFox and Google Chrome

```
<template>
  <div style="height: 100vh; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
    <h1>{{ result }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue } from 'vue-class-component';

export default class App extends Vue {
  private result = `Running..`;

  mounted() {
    fetch(`http://192.168.2.26:3000/files`).then(() => {
      console.log('Fetch succes');
      this.result = 'Fetch succes';
    }).catch(() => {
      console.log('Fetch error');
      this.result = 'Fetch error';
      console.log(this.result);
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

This is my console:

> Fetch error App.vue:13
>
> Fetch error App.vue:15

While the HTML still shows "Running.."

Comment: try using `this.$nextTick(() => { this.result = 'your message' })`

Comment: @AdarshMohan that works! Could you maybe explain why? :)

Comment: I am exactly not sure the reason, but `$nextTick` is what I usually uses when the reactivity dont work like expected. maybe the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick) can help you understand better